# Is using another method to complete a user task considered a fail if it isn't what I'm looking for?

Tags: usability-testing, task-completion

I designed a dashboard layout for my company's monitoring application and had a couple of users go through a usability test session while using the application to see how usable to dashboard is.

On one of the user tasks, I wanted them to use a graph on the dashboard to complete the task. However, some of the users used a detailed graph on another page to complete the task. Would this be considered a failed task? Or would it be considered as a completed task since they were able to find the answer they're looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't be considered a failed task, because the user has completed the task (so for all purposes, the requirement has been satisfied).

However, we often distinguish between 3 cases:

- **Ideal-path completion** - meaning the user has completed the task in the shortest/intended sequences of steps.
- **Divergent-path completion** - meaning the user has completed the task, but not using the ideal path.
- **No completion**

This correspond to green, amber and red in the following table (from a report):

[image: A task vs participant matrix, showing each cell coloured green, amber or red]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That makes more sense now. I found it odd to fail them even if they completed the task.. just not in the most efficient way.